# CSS: Vertical alignment issue in mobile display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Image**

[image]

HTML code [here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:414c).

**Question 1**:

Is this the correct way to add bootstrap classes?

**CSS:**

```
.hai {
   padding-top: 20%;
   padding-bottom: 20%;
   padding-left: 10%;
   padding-right: 10%;
}
```

**Question 2**:

I am not familiar with css. The above css gives a perfect output in (my) PC display (link to screenshots above), but in mobile view the output is not what i expected. Why is it not vertically center alligned in mobile view? What changes should be made?

Answer (score 0):

since you have padding top+bottom = 40%

i assume you should set container .hai height to 100-40 = 60%

edited:

try adding inside .hai { ... }

height: 60%;

Comment: Could you please specify what change should i make in the css?

Answer (score 0):

### You can center the container vertically using either relative/absolute positioning, or vertical-align .

**Relative/absolute positioning**

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
}
```

**Vertical-align**

```
#container_parent{
    display: table;
}
#container{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```